# C# Получить наименование дня недели на основании даты

Tags: c#

Есть дата DateTime _d. Как узнать наименование дня недели на языке, который является текущим на компьютере (русский)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Например, так:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(_d.DayOfWeek);
```

Если нужен язык, не являющийся системным (например, русский на английской системе), можно делать так:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru-RU").DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(_d.DayOfWeek);
```

---

Вот ещё пара официальных примеров из MSDN: [*Практическое руководство. Извлечение дня недели из конкретной даты*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb762911%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). И у `CurrentCulture` в `DateTimeFormat` есть [много чего интересного](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) тоже.

Comment: чего так сложно то :)

Comment: @Dmitry: Зато без магических констант :)

Comment: System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[(int)Convert.ToDateTime(_d).DayOfWeek]

Comment: @АлександрПузанов: Угу, или так. По идее `_d` уже и так `DateTime`.

Answer (score 4):

Вам надо прочитать про способы форматирование даты, а так вот ответ на ваш вопрос.

```
_d.ToString("dddd");
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает, изучу.